# Difference between net/http and net/http/fcgi in Golang

Tags: go, fastcgi

What's the difference?
If I use net/http/fcgi package, every request will be executed in new goroutine. It seems to be the same for net/http ListenAndServe...isn't it?
What advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Fcgi or cgi?  Which one are you really asking about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `net/http/fcgi` allows you to listen via the FastCGI protocol for new connections whereas the `net/http` ListenAndServe is there for listening for incoming http connections.  With a FastCGI listener you need an http server sitting in front of the Go process that is proxying incoming connections and sending requests via FastCGI to you Go process.

FastCGi can be useful if you have multiple services that you need to expose on the same port.  You can run something like Apache or Nginx as the front end and expose certain urls to your Go process via FastCGI.

If this is not your case and you just want to run a Go web server on a port, stick with `net/http`.

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to use Go + nginx? Is it better to use net/http/fcgi in Go?...or to redirect dynamic requests to standart Go webserver?

Comment: You could do it either way.  Nginx will do reverse http proxy service or FastCGI.  Since Go is already quite fast at parsing http requests, I think it's simpler just to utilize Nginx's reverse http proxy if you need a multi tiered deployment option.